# Display only subscribed items in Google Reader Play

Tags: google-reader

Google Reader Play seems to be showing 'suggested' items for me.

I can click on the settings and select different categories but I'd rather have it displaying my unread items from Google Reader.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose "View in Reader Play" from any folder's settings menu, but you can't do it for all of your folders or even an individual feed.

[image: screen shot]

http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/03/and-now-for-something-completely.html